# Determine whether a set of points in d-dimensions are in convex position

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I have a set of points in d-dimensions.
I want to check whether they are in convex position or not.
My approach was to implement QuickHull and run it on the points, but I failed to implement a robust QuickHull algorithm on my own (need it to be written in Rust and compiled without standard library). It would end up in edge-cases a lot and fail.

Any other approaches I should know about?

Comment: Is d small (2 or 3)? How do you want to handle degenerate cases?

Comment: How do you see that it fails ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Make convex hull and check if all points are either in vertices or on the border planes?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: I am asking the OP how he knows that it fails.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat d > 3, and what do you mean by how do I want to handle degenerate cases?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Before implementing the algorithm on Rust, I implemented it in Python and compared my results to scipy.spatial.ConvexHull's results. In a lot of cases I get different results, and after debugging my code, I saw in the paper I was basing my implementation on (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/235815.235821) that in page 11 they describe a lot of edge cases which they checked in their implementation, and I do not have the knowledge to do so myself, so I'm checking if there are any other approaches I should go with, which might be easier and faster to implement.

Comment: First question is if you are hitting those edge cases or if your implementation is just flawed.

Comment: @RonMichal if you're unable to implement it based off the paper, perhaps find an open-source implementation of a convex-hull algorithm and translate it to rust then. I doubt there's any smart way to solve this without building the convex hull in the process, so it's unlikely that you'll get any useful answers here.